# Generating string combinations in r

Tags: r, string, combinations

I have a string with the length of 6 characters a="100111". I want to generate all possible combinations of characters in a. The "1" in position 1,4,5,6 can become "0" but the "0" in position 2 and 3 remain as "0".

I want an output

```
b <- c("000000", "100000", "000100","000010","000001", "100100", 
      "100010", "100001","000011","000101","000110", "000011", ..., "100111")
```

I tried using strsplit and try to generate the series using a loop by changing the 0 and 1 by locating them using a which () and replacing them. I cannot get the output.

First problem I encounter is when I try try to add all the string together.

Can somebody help me on how to generate this series? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `expand.grid()`:

```
a <- "100111"
a_split <- strsplit(a, "")[[1]]
a_list <- lapply(a_split, function(i) 0:i)
a_cases <- expand.grid(a_list)
sapply(1:nrow(a_cases), function(i) paste(a_cases[i, ], collapse = ""))
##  [1] "000000" "100000" "000100" "100100" "000010" "100010" "000110" "100110" "000001" "100001" "000101"
## [12] "100101" "000011" "100011" "000111" "100111"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
a1 <- strsplit(a, "")[[1]]
i1 <- which(a1==1)
unlist(lapply(length(i1):0, function(i) 
  combn(i1, i, FUN = function(x) paste(replace(a1, x, 0), collapse=""))))
#[1] "000000" "000001" "000010" "000100" "100000" "000011" "000101" "000110"
#[9] "100001" "100010" "100100" "000111" "100011" "100101" "100110" "100111"
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is the output different from @Stibu reply

Comment: @Mohanasundar `expand.grid` creates all combinations, but `combn` gets only the combinations that are needed.  For example `expand.grid(1:3, 1:3); combn(1:3, 2)`.  As you have not showed the fulll list of combinations in expected output, I don't know which one you want

Comment: @akrun I think that you just missed the case, where none of the 1s are replaced by zero (i.e., the combination that is identical to `a`). If you replace `rev(seq_along(i1))` by (for example) `length(i1):0`, you get the same result as I do (up to the ordering).